# How do I wire a new range to old wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, range

I am replacing an in-wall oven with a oven/stove. The wiring in the wall is a 2 wire #6, and a ground wire. One of the wires has red arrows on it, the other solid black. (obviously 220V) and I traced them to the breaker box. Both the solid black and the black with red arrow both go into a 50 amp double breaker, and the ground wire goes to the grounding bar.

My stove has a three prong plug: red, black white and ground. With only two hot wires and no neutral coming from the wall, how do I wire the 2 hot and neutral?

Comment: Are you installing a range (free standing oven/stove), or a built-in oven/stove unit?  Is the ground wire bare or insulated? What size is the ground wire? Is the cable feeding the device type SE cable?

Comment: configure the bonding jumper appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the cord on your range for a 3-pin range cord (NEMA 10-50) and configure the bonding jumper appropriately, then install a NEMA 10-50 receptacle for your stove.  (This is allowed for existing branch circuits, just not new ones.)

Comment: Doesn't he need a neutral from the panel? Doesn't some portion of the new range need 110?

Comment: @bib -- the NEMA 10 uses a combined neutral/ground conductor (blame the 50's, when 10/3 and bigger NM wasn't a thing so you had to wire up the range outlet with type SE cable instead, which lacks a separate ground)

Comment: The neutral is not used in this case.  For a retrofit that's fine.